# What is value:while{} mean in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop

I've read some tutorials which using this syntax in Java, but I don't know what it's mean?

```
newNumber:while (1 <= 500) {
  // do something
}
```

I don't understand what `newNumber:while` mean and I can't find it on [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: Whoever originally wrote `newNumber:while` is poor coder.  Keywords should always have space around them.  Conventionally, a label appears on a line by itself.  I’ve seen it placed on the same line as the start of a loop, but omitting the space after the `:` is obnoxious, and serves no purpose other than to look L33T by writing code that’s deliberately harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

newValue is label here. You can use it with break and continue statement. It becomes relevant for nesting loops when you want to jump from inside the nested loop.